# How to order text that contains double colons (::)

Tags: mysql, sql

To order by name I'm using `'order by name`'

But the names contain double colons : `'::'`

How can I order by the text that occurs subsequent to the double colons ?

So :

```
aaaa::bbbb
aaaa::aaaa
aaaa::1234
aaaa::a1234
```

Will be ordered :

```
aaaa::1234
aaaa::aaaa
aaaa::a1234
aaaa::bbbb
```

Comment: For that EXACT example; `ORDER BY RIGHT(name, 4)`. All you need to do is replace `RIGHT(name, 4)` with some code that always returns the portion of `name` that you want to order by.

Comment: The example is not clear because a standard ORDER BY would produce the same result.

Comment: Did you mean double colons? If not, I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: @Amadan yes, double colons, question updated

Comment: Can you provide another example? 'Cause with this one, a classical ORDER BY name will sort the records as you want.

Comment: @user470184 Will it always be the same prefix (i.e. `aaaa::` in your example)? Or could there be one record with `aa::`, another one with `aaa::` and a last one with `b::` for example?

Comment: @sp00m prefix will be different

Comment: your sorting , according to ascii values numbers come first before alphabets, so aaaa:1234 should come first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by the substring ans use [locate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to find where it starts:

```
order by substring(name, locate('::', name) + 3, 30)
```

It'll decrease performance since no index will be used.

Comment: +1 : For mentioning that this will negate any ability to use an index for pre-sorting.

Comment: @aF.l charindex function does not exist in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new field in MySQL then insert the second part of your text into it. Sort by uses various indexes and algorithms (such as divide and conquer).

As such it would not work on sorting on a specific portion of a specific string, and if you did manage to 'fake' a way of doing it, the performance would be *terrible* due to lack of indexes.

Sorry, I realise this probably isn't the answer your looking for, but I'm afraid the best way is the slightly longer way, but at least you can then do it at lighting fast speeds if you add an index to it :)

Comment: thanks, im not worries about speed, this is just a one off query

Comment: You could use something like ORDER BY RIGHT(name, INSTR(name,'::')) but this would be very very very slow

Comment: @JohnMitchell - I wouldn't say it would be `very very very` slow.  What if the result set the OP has is only 20 records.  The plan generated will note that no index relates to the final order, and so will be free to generate a plan that doesn't care about ordering and then sort as a final step.  And sorting 20 records isn't hard.  If this was to be applied to a whole table, with a million records, that's different as sorting has a non-linear cost.

Comment: @Dems obviously everything is comparative, however the cost goes from O(1) to O(N) when comparing the sorting of a pre-saved index to a dynamically generated (through search) sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You must split the text into two columns and order by the latter one. You can either split and join the columns in application code or use views and stored procedures to make it look like one column to a database client.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following approach

1. Get all records where All data is Alphabet after ::

   UNION
2. Get all records where All data is Numeric after ::

Answer (score 0):

about your sorting , according to ascii values numbers come first before alphabets, 
so aaaa:1234 should come first

You can retrieve the values and sort in PHP

[Navsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
<?php
$arr = array("aaaa::bbbb","aaaa::aaaa","aaaa::1234","aaaa::a1234");

$sec=$arr;
natsort($sec);

print_r ($sec);

?>
```